# XIRR gives #NUM! error when exchange rate is too low

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm testing the rate of return of some bitcoin trading and I'm using using XIRR, I can't use IRR cuz the time interval varies, sometimes I buy/sell several BTCs in a day, other times it takes a few weeks.

It works fine with 'sane' numbers, but as soon as I test if the market crashs to very low exchange rates the formula gives me a #NUM! error

Here's a working example

| datetime | cashflow | exc rate | BTCs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/22 10:00 | -60 | 280.000 | 0,00021429 |
| 01/01/22 10:01 | -60 | 270.000 | 0,00043651 |
| 01/01/22 10:02 | -60 | 260.000 | 0,00066728 |
| 06/01/22 10:00 | 120 | 300.000 | 0,00026728 |
| 06/01/22 10:10 | 41,54 | 155.398,84 | 0,00000000 |
|  |  |  |  |
| XIRR | -99,963% (a.a) | -48% (a.m.) | -2% (a.d.) |

`=XIRR(B2:B6;A2:A6) | =(1+B8)^(1/12)-1 | =(1+B8)^(1/365)-1`

Here's a the same example, except the last rates of btc is 1 cent lower

| datetime | cashflow | exc rate | BTCs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/22 10:00 | -60 | 280.000 | 0,00021429 |
| 01/01/22 10:01 | -60 | 270.000 | 0,00043651 |
| 01/01/22 10:02 | -60 | 260.000 | 0,00066728 |
| 06/01/22 10:00 | 120 | 300.000 | 0,00026728 |
| 06/01/22 10:10 | 41,53 | 155.398,83 | 0,00000000 |
|  |  |  |  |
| XIRR | #NUM! | #NUM! | #NUM! |

My workaround for now is to use `IFERROR('the xirr formula'; -100%)` but that messes the montlhy and daily rates

Is there a way to fix this, or a better workaround?

Comment: Can you please attach a copy of the Google Sheet?